# Trying to make an if statement that checks if a string contains a character using indexOf. Having a little bit of trouble

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-c++

I want it to be where if the string contains a certain character it would do one thing. For example if `Serial.readString();` reads X100Y100 then I want to check if it contains an X or not. What I have so far is:

```
void serialEvent() {
    serialData = Serial.readString();
    if (serialData.indexOf('X')) {
        serX.write(parseDataX(serialData));
    } else {
    // Doesnt contain the character X
    }
}
```

Would this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `X` is found, `indexOf()` will return its index. If it is found at index 0, your `if` statement will evaluate to false. Likewise, if `X` is not found, `indexOf()` will return `-1`, which your `if` statement will evaluate as true. To check if `X` exists in `serialData`, you need to check if `indexOf()` does not return `-1`:

```
if (serialData.indexOf('X') != -1)
```

See the [`indexOf()` documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/indexof/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks so much! Works great!